# Multiplicar 2 números aleatorios

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa donde aparezcan 2 números aleatorios y que el usuario los multiplique y ponga la respuesta. Si la respuesta es incorrecta, los 2 números se deben seguir generando hasta que acierte. Soy nuevo en programación, quisiera conseguir una idea de como realizarlo. Gracias :D

Comment: Tu pregunta lleva dos de cinco votos para terminar cerrada, deberías agregar que has intentado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta que te dio Ivan es correcta, pero yo no usaría recursividad de forma innecesaria ¿como qué lo justifica cuando puedes hacer lo mismo con un while y queda además más expresivo?

La otra cosa es usar `.format()` para imprimir números en pantalla. Cuesta un poquito al principio, pero más vale que lo utilices desde el inicio, para que te acostumbres. Puedes ver el punto [7.1.2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) de la documentación de Python

```
import random

correcto = False

while (not correcto):
    n1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    n2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    r = input('Cuanto es {} x {}'.format(n1, n2))
    if (int(r) == (n1 * n2)):
        correcto = True
        break
    print('Fallaste')

print('Acertaste')
```

Comment: Me agrada tu codigo pero me genera conflicto, segun tengo entendido los bucles generan mas presión sobre los procesos generando a largo plazo malas costumbres, al menos es lo que tengo entendido pero me encantaria leerte

Comment: ¿En dónde leíste eso? ¿Malas costumbres? ¿Como por qué? Si es una estructura básica. Desconozco como funciona internamente Python, pero en general, cuando usas recursividad, el interprete debe guardar una dirección de regreso a la llamada anterior

Comment: Lo estaba leyendo por la mañana (en México) pero tienes razón en que para algoritmos simples es mejor usar un bucle y malas costumbres para problemas de eficiencia mas complejos te dejo el link de mi lectura matituna por si te interesa, es ambientado a procesos y se puede escalar a ML

Comment: [Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=aJQILlLxRmAC&pg=PA440&lpg=PA440&dq=recursion+vs+loop+performance+python&source=bl&ots=CBcGxEV9YH&sig=ACfU3U3ZisiAen5yIXnhUJa6eEzbjttSJg&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivkv_U_OnpAhVNmK0KHX4sAn4Q6AEwEXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=recursion%20vs%20loop%20performance%20python&f=false) lo encuentras a partir de la pagina 440

Comment: OK gracias, lo checo. Me parece rarísimo, pero alguna razón habrá

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con el siguiente codigo:

```
from random import random #Importas random

def randomNumberCheck():#creasn tu funcion recursiva
  number1 = round(random()*10) #Generas primer numero aleatorio entre 1 y 10
  number2 = round(random()*10) #Generas segundo numero aletario entre 1 y 10
  answer = number1*number2 #Generas la respuesta correcta
  print("Multiplica ",number1," x ",number2) #Indicas al usuario
  ans = float(input("Ingrese su respuesta\n")) #Recibes del usuario
  if(ans==answer): #Comparas
    print("Ganaste :D") #Mensaje de gane
  else:
    print("Intenta de nuevo") #Mensaje de perdida
    randomNumberCheck() #Llamas a funcion recursiva otra vez hasta que ganes
randomNumberCheck()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
while True:
    n1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    n2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    result=n1*n2
    print("Cuanto es",n1,"*",n2)
    print("Ingresa tu respuesta")
    a=int(input())

    if a ==result:
        print("Acertaste")
        break
    else:
        print("fallaste")
```